# Stop variable from changing dynamically in a Makefile target

Tags: makefile, target

I placed the following Makefile in **/tmp**:

```
VAR := $$(basename $$(pwd))

do:
        echo $(VAR) && cd /usr && echo $(VAR) && cd /usr/share && echo $(VAR)
```

Running it, I expected this output:

```
tmp
tmp
tmp
```

But instead get:

```
tmp
usr
share
```

How do I make it give me the former output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't escape the `$` if you want make to evaluate the values.  By escaping them you've asked the shell to do the evaluation.  You're asking the shell to run this command:

```
echo $(basename $(pwd)) && cd /usr && echo $(basename $(pwd)) && cd /usr/share && echo $(basename $(pwd))
```

which gives the output you see: the shell runs one command at a time so the previous command takes effect before the next one.  If you want to get one value in a shell script, you can use:

```
VAR := $$(basename $$(pwd))

do:
        tmp=$(VAR); echo $$tmp && cd /usr && echo $$tmp && cd /usr/share && echo $$tmp
```

which assigns the shell variable `tmp` to the value you want then uses that in your script.

Or, you can compute the value into a `make` variable instead and use that everywhere:

```
VAR := $(notdir $(CURDIR))

do:
        echo $(VAR) && cd /usr && echo $(VAR) && cd /usr/share && echo $(VAR)
```

(note you're not escaping the `$` in the assignment of `VAR`, so this is using `make` functions not shell commands).

Comment: Using `VAR=$(shell basename $$(pwd))` also worked well. Is it good practice?

Comment: The last version results in `/tmp`, but me wants `tmp`.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the last version.  Regarding using `shell`, yes it will work.  I wouldn't call it a _good practice_ because you're running three instances of the exact same shell command which is inefficient.  Even if you change the `=` to a `:=` so you only run it once, it's not so efficient to run a shell when you could just use make's built-in functions.  But you'll get the same result and it's unlikely you'll notice the inefficiency, so it might be "good practice" if it makes more sense to you.  But I wouldn't use it.